# How can I include a phtml file in Magento2 using block type="core/template"?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento2

I have done the following:

```
Magento 2 EE Admin > Content > Pages > Add New
```

Page is called Hello World

The content is:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/Modules/About.phtml"}}
```

I have gone to and created.

```
App/design/frontend/Magento/Blank/Modules/About.phtml
```

When I visit localhost/m2/hello

The page loads expected but does not load the about.phtml which has a plain text call saying

```
<p>Hello this file is correct</p>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="BlockName" template="Magento_Blank::PathOftemplate/About.phtml"}}
```

**In magento 2,** *`Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`* eq to *`core/template`*

Comment: This still does not work, strangely

Comment: That's exactly the right way! thank you very much Amit and Marius!

Answer (score 2):

in cms page i used below code its working fine

```
<p>{{block class="Sugarcode\Test\Block\Test" name="BlockName" template="Sugarcode_Test::test.phtml"}}</p>
```

**Sugarcode\Test\Block\Test**:-  my block or else you can use `"Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"` 
**Sugarcode_Test::test.phtml**:- `app\code\Sugarcode\Test\view\frontend\templates\test.phtml`  (template file )